# Check if input matches string argument in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I need to check if a commandline argument matches the one in a bash script, here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# lets call this script.sh

myFunction() {
if [[ $2 == '--log' ]]; then
    echo "hello world" >> file.log
else
    echo "Unknown argument"
fi
}

myFunction
```

Sample input:

```
bash script.sh --log
```

But doesn't seem to write anything into file.log

Comment: I guess you know that `$2` in a function is not the second command-line argument but the second **function** argument?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in what way it doesn't work. What input do you use, what output/result/behavior do you get and what would you expect.  The script defines a function but does not call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the script's arguments to `myFunction`:

```sh
myFunction "$@"
```

The `"$@"` means "all the arguments passed to this script."

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks much